# Htaccess, How do I redirect this dynamic URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a strange redirect situation that I cannot get to work.

www.example.com/?NR

www.example.com/?PV

I need to get these two URL's rewritten and redirected to the home page but I can't get it to work. Here is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^NR$ [NC]
RewriteRule www.example.com/ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PV$ [NC]
RewriteRule www.example.com/ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

We bought this site and I have no reference to what those pages might actually be, they just need to be redirected and rewritten properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one rule should work for both of your requirements:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(NR|PC)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Remember that `RewriteRule` only matches REQUEST_URI which is URI part without domain name and query string.

`/` in target URI is for your home URL and `?` in the end is to strip any existing query string.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)